# scrape linkedin people search with python

Tags: python, web-scraping, linkedin-api

I want to scrape the result of people search using linkedin.

```
url='https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/people/?facetCurrentCompany=%5B%222525300%22%5D&facetGeoRegion=%5B%22fi%3A0%22%5D&keywords=python&origin=FACETED_SEARCH'
import bs4
import requests
res=requests.get(url)
soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
```

There is no error, but the problem is when I click on the link the result shows that there is one person matched my search criteria. and I cannot find that person in the soup result generated from Python code.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 7):

You are trying to scrape data, which is available to logged in users only.

You should use the official LinkedIn REST API and authenticate via OAuth2.
Give it a try: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/rest-api

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried the linkedin API; but I think now it does not support searching for people or job, i can only use the API to get my public profile

Comment: The LinkedIn docs are quite obscure. Maybe check out: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2

Answer (score 5):

I would use an open source that already done the hard work and try to modify it to my needs. For example:

https://github.com/ericfourrier/scrape-linkedin

Note: this will only work for public data

Comment: Hi, I have tried this one, but it has an error "pylinkedin.exceptions.ServerIpBlacklisted: Linkedin blacklists ips for unauthentified http requests, Aws, Digital Ocean"

Comment: Seems like linkedIn blocked the default IP that this code uses (which makes sense). You'll have to find\use a proxy from a different source.

Comment: and also this library is used for searching a specific profile, I have to know the name of the person I want to search. However, in my case, I want to search for criteria such as people has skill in Python, so I do not know whom I am going to search.

Comment: Like I said in the original answer. This code will need modification for your own needs. But at least it provides a way to access linkedIn out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

The Rest API method is not good for scraping, as it has several restrictions & limits.

Using Selenium for automation can scrape as much data as possible and even enables you to perform actions on LinkedIn.

For scraping I recommend using https://github.com/austinoboyle/scrape-linkedin-selenium. It covers most of the needs but has several bugs as of now(as LinkedIn updates their site frequently).

I am using modified version in a Flask Backend [here](https://github.com/abhijithvijayan/EpiMatch/)

It's better to fork the library and use the scraping methods to your needs.

Comment: The flask backend will be open-sourced soon.